# Как сделать лучше такой эффект(repeating-linear-gradient)?

Tags: css, css3

[image: Нужен такой эффект]

блок высотой в 500 пикселей, данный эффект только снизу на всю ширину. Пока получилось только это https://jsfiddle.net/zdb15uun/1/

```
    <ol>
         <li>repeating gradient
             <div id="grad1"></div>
         </li>
          <li>Zebra pattern   
           <div id="grad2"></div>
       </li>     
          <li>Zebra pattern   3
             <div id="grad3"></div>
           </li>   
       </ol>
     div {
     display: block;
     width: 50%;
     height: 80px;
     border-color: #000000;
      padding: 10px;
     }

     #grad {
          background-image: -moz-repeating-linear-                 gradient(180deg,rgb(26,198,204),rgb(26,198,204) 7%, rgb(100,100,100) 10%);
           background-image: -webkit-repeating-linear-gradient(180deg,rgb(26,198,204),rgb(26,198,204) 7%, rgb(100,100,100) 10%);
          background-image: -o-repeating-linear-gradient(180deg,rgb(26,198,204),rgb(26,198,204) 7%, rgb(100,100,100) 10%);
       background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(180deg,rgb(26,198,204),rgb(26,198,204) 7%, rgb(100,100,100) 10%);
    }

         #grad1 {
           background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(209, 232, 220, 1), rgba(209, 232, 220, 1) 75px, rgba(212, 238, 222, 1) 10px, rgba(212, 238, 222, 1) 150px);
    }

 #grad2 {
  background-color: #068445;
   background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(6, 132, 69, 1),    rgba(6, 132, 69, 1) 75px, rgba(27, 167, 80, 1) 10px, rgba(27, 167, 80, 1) 150px);
    }
```

не знаю, как его сделать выцветающим кверху пикселей эдак на 75

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если градиент сверху белый, а не прозрачный, можно попробовать просто накрыть его сверху другим градиентом. Если нужна именно прозрачность, то не знаю.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background-image: 
    linear-gradient(to bottom, white, transparent),
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, antiquewhite, antiquewhite 3em, silver 3em, silver 6em);
}
```